# How to tell which MKPinAnnotation has been pressed?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, mapkit

i have an `MKMapView` and have a whole bunch of `MKPinAnnotations` being shown and all of them have call out feature which shows a more detail view depending on were the location is..

How can I implement a method that tells which pin has been pressed out of the group so it shows a more detail view about that location?

Answer (score 2):

implement the `MKMapView` delegate:

```
- (void) mapView: (MKMapView *) mapView didSelectAnnotationView: (MKAnnotationView *) view
```

and you can do whatever you need in there.

But i think you are really after enabling the map callout accessory.  See MapCallouts sample application http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009746